# What is the difference between modelMatrix.setTranslate() and modelMatrix.translate() in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

So I'm learning to program with WebGL in JavaScript and two terms that seem very similar have cropped up.

```
modelMatrix.setTranslate(0,0,0);
modelMatrix.translate(0,0,0);
```

Zero was put in just for an example and modelMatrix is a modelling matrix.

What is the difference between set translate and translate?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Thise funcitions are not part of WebGL. You seem to be using some framework which is providing that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

`setTranslate` works like a setter. It creates a new translation matrix from the parameters and stores it to `modelMatrix`. For instance let's say the value of `modelMatrix` is

```
1 0 0 2
0 1 0 2
0 0 1 2
0 0 0 1
```

and when you apply this code `modelMatrix.setTranslate(0,0,0);` it will become

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

In contrast `translate` multiplies the matrix already stored in `modelMatrix` by the matrix created from the parameters and stores the result to `modelMatrix`.
For instance the value of `modelMatrix` is

```
1 0 0 2
0 1 0 2
0 0 1 2
0 0 0 1
```

and when you apply this code `modelMatrix.translate(0,0,0);` it will become

```
1 0 0 2   1 0 0 0   1 0 0 2
0 1 0 2 x 0 1 0 0 = 0 1 0 2
0 0 1 2   0 0 1 0   0 0 1 2
0 0 0 1   0 0 0 1   0 0 0 1
```